# Evaluate the Double Integral at the Following Region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, solution-verification, volume

## Problem Statement

Evaluate $\iint_R xdA$, where R is the region bounded by $x=\ln(y)$, $x=0$,$y=e$.

### My Work:

$$\int_0^e\int_0^{\ln(y)}x\ dx\ dy$$
or
$$\int_0^1 \int_{e^x}^e x\ dy\ dx$$

#### My Problem

Which integral setup is correct I tried doing the problems both ways Type 1, and Type 2, and I got different answers for both? I am confused generally on how to setup a Type 1, and Type 2 double integral for the same problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You must have a typo in the statement of the problem.

Comment: I am pluging them into Wolfram and seeing if I get the same answer

Comment: @Paul On desmos i get 1.359, and 0.359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type 2 integral is not properly set. It should be

$$
\int_1^e \int_0^{\ln y}x \, dx\, dy.
$$

[image]

Comment: Ah, Yes your right because the function intercepts $x=0$ at $y=1$.